# How can these two subgroups be normal?

Tags: group-theory

This is an exercise from Rotman's book *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups.* Given groups H and K and their direct product $H \times K$, show that $H \times 1$ and $1 \times K$ are normal subgroups of $H \times K$. I don't see how that would be possible unless one assumes both H and K are abelian—assumption which is made nowhere in the text.

This is my reasoning. If $H \times 1 \unlhd H \times K$, then $(a,b)(H \times 1) = (H \times 1)(a,b)$ for every $(a,b) \in H\times K$. In particular, we should have $(a,b)(h,1)=(ah,b)=(ha,b)=(h,1)(a,b)$ and ultimately $ah=ha$, for every choice of (a,b) and h, which means H is abelian, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you look up what it means to be a normal subgroup (especially compared to the center of the group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(h,k)(h_1,1)(h^{-1},k^{-1})=(hh_1h^{-1},1)$ which is in $H \times 1$, as $hh_1h^{-1}\in H$

I leave the $1\times K$ case to you.
In your method, you tried to prove that any element in a normal subgroup is fixed under conjugation. But the definition of a normal subgroup only requires that elements be closed under conjugation.

Comment: I see the mistake I was making. Thanks a lot!